# Deleting a character from the entries of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe where a row called `'Months'` has entries in form: `1M` , `12M` etc. So I wanted to get rid of the `M` letter. 
I have tried using the `.replace()` function but had no success in doing so: 
`df['Months'].replace('M','')` 
what is wrong in my implementation and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Comment: You are really close, need `df['Months'].replace('M','', regex=True)` for replace substrings

Comment: Or maybe `df['Months'].str.replace('M','')` (untested)

Comment: `.str.replace()` did the job!

Comment: It is dupe, so no answer :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for ".str.replace", i.e.:

```
df['Months'] = df['Months'].str.replace('M','')
```

The ".str" functions apply a string function to each entry of the database; instead the ".replace" one replaces all objects, so in case you should be doing:

```
for i in range(1,13):
    df['Months'] = df['Months'].replace('{}M'.format(i),str(i))
```

which is of course clumsier and likely slower.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df['Months'].str.replace('M', '')`.

The difference:

- [**`pd.Series.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) matches on the entire entry in a series.
- [**`pd.Series.str.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) matches substrings of entries in a series.